# Adding onclick event to li element in IE6

Tags: javascript, events, internet-explorer-6

So I have a list, and I want to dynamically add an event via JavaScript. I have it working great in Firefox, but I also need it to work in IE6 (ugh), but it's required. It doesn't have to be pretty, just needs to work. The event that triggers simply removes the item from the list. I am not sure what I need to do to get it working. Here is small piece of what I have so far. The ids are unique, I just put that one in as an example. It works great in all newer browsers.

```
    var id = "123456";
    var list = document.createElement("ul");
    var listElement = document.createElement("li");
    listElement.setAttribute("id", id);
    listElement.setAttribute("onclick", "removeFromList('" + id + "')");
    listElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content));
    list.appendChild(listElement);
    document.getElementById('myElement').appendChild(list);
```

Comment: Could you provide some more information? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Please provide the event handlers as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't have an IE6 to test this, but replacing the onclick-line:

```
listElement.setAttribute("onclick", "removeFromList('" + id + "')");
```

with this might work:

```
listElement.onclick = function(){ removeFromList(id); };
```

you also could use [attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for IE and stick to you old solution (or better use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)) on the newer ones.

Answer (score 2):

Pure javascript, should work in IE6 :

```
var id = "123456";
var list = document.createElement("ul");
var listElement = document.createElement("li");
listElement.setAttribute("id", id);
listElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content));
list.appendChild(listElement);
document.getElementById('myElement').appendChild(list);

if( listElement.addEventListener ) {
    listElement.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        removeFromList( id );}, false );
} else {
    listElement.attachEvent( "onclick", function(e) {
        removeFromList( id );});
}
```