# Passing event object to addEvent function

Tags: javascript

I have crossbrowser addEvent Listener Code and I need to pass event object 
This works in Chrome but not in Ie.
So what should I do?

```
function addEvent(element, eventName, eventFunction) { 
        if(element.attachEvent) //Internet Explorer
            element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, function (e) {eventFunction.call(element);}); 
        else if(element.addEventListener) //Firefox & company
            element.addEventListener(eventName, function (e) { eventFunction(e) }, false); 
    }


addEvent(window, 'keydown', changeSpeed);
```

Comment: Note [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529358/adding-onclick-event-to-li-element-in-ie6)

Answer (score 0):

On older IE, the event object is not passes as an argument, it's a global called `event`. So the minimal mod is:

```
function addEvent(element, eventName, eventFunction) { 
    if(element.attachEvent) //Internet Explorer
        element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, function () {eventFunction.call(element, event);}); 
    // No argument ------------------------------------^ use global -------------------^
    else if(element.addEventListener) //Firefox & company
        element.addEventListener(eventName, function (e) { eventFunction(e) }, false); 
}
```

But a couple of notes:

1. I would check for `addEventListener` *first*, as some browsers may provide `attachEvent` as a backstop to deal with old IE-specific code.
2. There are several other differences between the behavior of `attachEvent` and `addEventListener`, particularly around preventing the default behavior of an event and stopping event propagation. This `addEvent` function doesn't address those at all.
3. You're not setting `this` correctly in your `addEventListener` version.

Rather than reinventing this wheel, I'd go shopping for an existing road-tested wheel and use that.

Comment: @user2950593: "Doesn't work" is not a useful problem description. What are you expecting, and what happens instead? I can assure you that the above **does** pass the event object to the handler on IE.

Comment: Let's write like this :   `  `element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, function () { console.log( event.keyCode);eventFunction.call(element,event);}); `This doesn't console anything

Comment: @user2950593: It would on IE8 (if you had the console open). Proof: http://jsbin.com/ICOFido/1/edit (but I avoided using `console.log`). But again: I would **not** recommend reinventing this wheel.

Answer (score 0):

it is easier to pass the event object directly to the calling function

```
function addEvent(element, eventName, eventFunction) { 
    if(element.attachEvent) //Internet Explorer
        element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, eventFunction);
    else if(element.addEventListener) //Firefox & company
        element.addEventListener(eventName, eventFunction, false); 
    else //old browser
        element["on" + eventName] = eventFunction;
}
```

**Ok on IE9, Firefox & co**

```
<input type="text" id="test">
<script>
addEvent(document.getElementById('test'),'keypress',function(e){
    keyCode =(window.event)?window.event.keyCode:e.which;
    alert(keyCode);});
</script>
```